# Reset and Add new permissions to Root Folders, Sub Folders, and Files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Case1
  ===== Accounting
  ===== Audits
  ===== Data
Case2
  ===== Accounting
  ===== Audits
  ===== Data
...
```

I have thousands of Case (root folders) on a share drive and over the years, the permissions have become a mess, so I need to go through all the folders, subfolders, and files and set the proper permissions. This is what I need to set

```
Root folder (case1, case2....caseN)
   case_admin (Full Control)
   case_root (List Folder Contents)

Accounting
    case_admin (Full Control)
    case_accounting (Modify)

Audits
    case_admin (Full Control)
    case_auditing (Modify)

Data
    case_admin (Full Control)
    case_data (Modify)
```

I am not sure if I should remove all permissions first because wouldn't that stop me from adding new permissions, but I also thought that removing everything and just adding the ones I need would be easier.  Here is what I have so far, based on just one root folder.

```
$filepath = 'L:\case1'
$user     = 'domain\userTORemove'

$folders = Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse -Directory

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder.FullName

    foreach ($access in $acl.Access) {
        if ($access.IdentityReference.Value -eq $user) {
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($access) | Out-Null
        }

        if($folder.FullName -eq "Accounting")
        {
             $ace = New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule ("case_admin", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
   $acl.AddAccessRule($ace)

 $ace = New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule ("case_root", "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
 $acl.AddAccessRule($ace)

Set-Acl -Path 'L:\case1' -AclObject $acl
        }

    }

    Set-Acl -Path $folder.FullName -AclObject $acl
}
```

So in a nutshell, I need to iterate over all root and sub folders and set the permissions on the root folder and then set the permissions on the subfolder and the permissions are based on the name of the subfolder.

I have no way of knowing what permissions are on every folder, so if I do conditional removes, I might miss something, so that is why I mentioned just removing all permissions first

Comment: You might want to consider setting the permissions you need, _then_ iterating over the ACLs, and removing the ones that are no longer needed.

Comment: What if the ACE exists already, but I need to change it from Full Control to Modify for example?  Would it make sense to remove and re-add or is there an option to alter permissions?

Comment: You can modify permissions; the suggestion I made was to minimize the chances of the situation you expressed concern over with respect to removing the ACLs.

Comment: I'd do it in 2 steps: 1) set exclusive admin access on the root and then cascade the "inheritance" down the tree. This will "default" ACLs to inherit mode 2) set those that you need beyond admin access.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that `Get-Acl` basically creates a template of ACE's based on the current access rules of the file/folder/whatever. You can then modify that template however you want (remove everybody, and add back specific users/groups), and it will have no affect on the original object until you apply that template to it with `Set-Acl`.

So, I would remove everything but the kind of default items. I would leave anything with 'Administrators' in the name (local admin group, domain admin, whatever), as well as the SYSTEM account. I would also leave 'OWNER CREATOR', but that one's just personal preference. I'll stick with those for my example.

If this were me I would loop through the caseX folders, and for each folder I would then loop through the subfolders, strip all but the 3 accounts noted above, and then add back in the appropriate group for the folder. To get that group I would setup a hashtable defining folder name to associated group name before the loops. After the subfolders are done I would basically do the same thing for the root case folder, and then move to the next case folder.

```
# Setup a hashtable to lookup group name by folder name
$FolderGroup = @{
    'Accounting' = 'case_Accounting'
    'Audit' = 'case_Auditing'
    'Data' = 'case_Data'
}

# Loop through all root case folders
ForEach($CaseFolder in (GCI L:\Case* -Directory))
{
    #Loop through subfolders of current case folder
    ForEach($Folder in (GCI $CaseFolder -Directory)){
        $ACL = Get-Acl $Folder
        # Remove access for any user other than Administrators, the Creator/Owner, and the local SYSTEM account
        $ACL.Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -notmatch "Administrators|Creator owner|system"}|%{$ACL.RemoveAccessRule($_)|Out-Null}
        # Add the department back
        $ACE = New-Object New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule ($FolderGroup[($Folder.Name)], "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
        $ACL.AddAccessRule($ACE)

        # Apply the modified ACL to the directory
        Set-Acl $Folder $ACL
    }

    $ACL = Get-Acl $CaseFolder
    # Remove access for any user other than Administrators, the Creator/Owner, and the local SYSTEM account
    $ACL.Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -notmatch "Administrators|Creator owner|system"}|%{$ACL.RemoveAccessRule($_)|Out-Null}
    # Add the admin and root ACE's
    $AdminACE = New-Object New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule ('case_admin', "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $RootACE = New-Object New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule ('case_root', "Read,Traverse", "None", "None", "Allow")
    $ACL.AddAccessRule($AdminACE)
    $ACL.AddAccessRule($RootACE)

    # Apply modified ACL to root case folder
    Set-Acl $CaseFolder $ACL
}
```